# When provisioning the AWS instance with the help of Terraform is giving me an error when I use community AMI id

Tags: terraform

I am getting this error when I provision the same "Error launching source instance: UnsupportedOperation: The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported."

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by increasing the instance type to large type.